# Subscribing to the wrong Topic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, robot, realtime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem is that I want to subscribe to the Topic "joy" but from a class.

Let's say that i have a class named My_Class.

As protected method i wrote the subscriber.

```
protected:
   
 ros::Subscriber my_subscriber;
```

Then i iniatlized it.

```
my_subscriber = nh_.subscribe("joy", 1, &My_Class::my_subscriber_cb, this);
```

Then i wrote my Callback Function

```
void my_subscriber_cb(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg){}
```

Then i initialised my node like this:

```
    // ROS-Node Initialisation
    ros::init(argc, argv, "TEST_CORE", ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
```

The problem is that at the end when i show the topic with **rostopic list**

I get a topic named `TEST_CORE/joy`. So I'm subscribing to `TEST_CORE/joy` and not to `/joy` .

What can i do or change to get the Data of my gamepad from the right Topic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360814/subscribing-to-the-wrong-topic/) by [Slachcrash](https://answers.ros.org/users/55285/slachcrash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-09-02**:
Could it be that your nodehandle is private? I.e. `nh_("~")`?  this would explain why the topic is put in the node namespace.

Otherwise, you could always [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap)...

**Comment by [Slachcrash](https://answers.ros.org/users/55285/slachcrash/) on 2020-09-02**:
Hello. Yes i had my nodehandle like this `nh_ = ros::NodeHandle("~");` I removed the `"~"` and it worked. Thanks. But I'm afraid it will bring some problems with it. I have all my code written in `node.cpp` file. Can you explain the remap tool ? how can i write that in a correct way, because i tried it and it didn't work.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-09-03**:
posted as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure to have your publishers and subscribers set up with the correct "namespace". For this, set the NodeHandle correctly. You are using a so-called "private" nodehandle. See [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles) for details.

Using NodeHandles correctly will not bring any problems, you just have to understand what they are and what they are used for. Good practice is to have all pubs/subs in the node namespace (i.e. `ros::NodeHandle()`) and all parameters in the private namespace (i.e.  `ros::NodeHandle("~")`).

I'm not quite sure what you mean with "explain the remap tool". In the end, this just takes a topic name that is specified in code (the `"from"` part) and changes it to another (the  `"to"` part). (The `"from"` needs to be exactly how the topic is named in your node.) So you don't have to change the code if you have, e.g. multiple drivers of the same type and want to now if that particular message is from driver A or driver B...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Slachcrash](https://answers.ros.org/users/55285/slachcrash/) on 2020-09-03**:
Thank you very much. This solved my issue. ;).